# Atari Punk Console with 7400 chips?

Tags: 555, generator, 7400

How would I create a stepped tone generator using 7400 logic?

For the first part, it's easy to have same range generator, with an additional transistor.

Is there any way to make the same range a monostable for the second?

[image]

Comment: Personally I never like these "is it possible to..." because as soon as someone says "No, not possible" there's another person showing you how it can be done. Making questions like this rather pointless.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie seeing as the actual question is *'is it possible to.....?'* then should be a simple enough question to answer. Yes. Yes it is possible somehow or some way. Answer complete!

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it better to use a small microcontroller instead? Absolutely.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ¯\(°_o)/¯ doing 555 and 74xx in 2018 is a mostly competitive task than practical. Suggestion to use a microcontroller is nonsense in that case. I don't think that's it's so trivial to create an RC-circuit that would drive 74xx monostable with the same range as 555.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the piece that I was looking for. It's the circuit that extends 74121 timings enough to be monostable for atari punk console.

[image]